# Java: How to create an array object with a constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I could use help/direction on how to build a constructor that receives (for example 1, 2, 3) int's and stores them into an array object called arr2.

Part I:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

Create an Arrays object using the first constructor
Arrays arr1 = new Arrays(5);


Arrays arr2 = new Arrays (1,2,3);
}
```

Part II:

```
public class Arrays {

private int [] array;
private int count;

public Arrays(int[] arr){

    int[] array = arr;
    array= arr;
    count = arr.length;
}}
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for var args method parameter.

Comment: This is an interesting problem: if you call it as `int[] a = new int[] {1,2,3}; Arrays arr1 = new Arrays(a);` then you want to *copy* the passed-in array argument. But if you call it as `Arrays arr2 = new Arrays(1,2,3);` then you don't want to copy the array, because it would waste CPU time and memory, since you could just save a *reference* to the passed argument in the Arrays object. C++ already allows this optimization through rvalue references, but Java doesn't. You'll have to copy the array in every case even if you don't need to.

Comment: your local variable `int[] array` hides the *member variable* that is also called `arrays`. To access the member variable instead, you'll have to reference it fully qualified with _this_: `this.array = arr`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
public class Arrays {

    private int [] array;

    public Arrays(int... arr){
        array = arr.clone();
    }

    public int get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

Changes from your code:

1. The constructor uses varargs (look it up).
2. There is no need to store the count; if you want the count the count, use `array.length()`.
3. The array is *copied*. This means you can change the original array that you passed in, but the values in the Arrays object won't be affected.
4. I've added a getter method.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this constructor with var args

```
public Arrays(int... arr) {

    int[] array = arr;
    array= arr;
    count = arr.length;
}
```